# nginx redirect for old wordpress articles

Tags: regex, nginx

we relaunched our wordpress site some time ago and i am trying to negate our google crawler errors.

we have more than 10k errors on trackback urls with a simple pattern. And it is easy enough to write a small script and have them fixed one by one but i was thinking if this could be solved with one simple rewrite rule within the nginx server config

old pattern:
{slug}/{id}/trackback

should redirect to: {slug}

sadly i am rly bad at regex expressions and have little experience in writing rewrite rules. What i know is that i should have a location which is telling nginx when to execute the desired rewrite rule and i was thinking on something like this

```
location ^.*/trackback {
     rewrite ^.*/[0-9].*/trackback /$1
}
```

when i try this rule i get `unexpected "}"` error message when restarting nginx

also that the location pattern is very identical to the rewrite statement, looks very fishy to me, maybe there is a better solution?

## update

current version:

```
location ~^(.*)/trackback {
    rewrite ^(.*)/[0-9]+/trackback $1 last;
}
```

the syntax issue is gone but the rule does not apply / is not triggered
here an example

`/my-test-article/12312/trackback` should now be redirected to
`/my-test-article`

but it does not

## update 2

this one is working (changed `last` to `redirect`and escaped the slashes)

```
location ~ ^(.*)\/trackback {
    rewrite ^(.*)\/[0-9]+\/trackback $1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: You might try an external redirect by changing the `last` to `redirect`.

Comment: @RichardSmith yes! that was it, thx! will update my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is probably a missing `;` after the `rewrite` rule. You are also missing a `~` operator in the `location` directive (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details). And you are missing a capture.

You are right that there is duplication in that the `location` regex needs testing, then the `rewrite` regex needs testing, which probably duplicates effort.

As the rewrite rule is quite specific, it should probably be placed in the `server` block above all of the `location` blocks.

If `id` is a purely numeric field, something like this should work:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/[0-9]+/trackback $1 last;
```

Comment: thx! i was able to fix the syntax issue with your help but the rule is not triggered )- : i will update my post accordingly

Comment: >  And you are missing a capture. 
what does **capture** mean in this context? sry english is not my first language

Comment: @braunbeard I was referring to the `()` used in a regex to capture the value of `$1`